# Facebook graph api - review / rating data with Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have recently gone through the facebook app approval process, and have been granted permissions for "Page Public Content Access"

We would like to retrieve ratings and reviews for businesses via the graph api. The documentation for Page Public Content Access states that "Readable data includes business metadata, public comments, posts, and **reviews**" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/)

We are able to retrieve the overall_star_rating and rating_count fields using our app token via *{page-id}/?fields=overall_star_rating,rating_count*, however when we attempt to access "ratings" and its subfields such as reviewer, reviewer text etc via *{page-id}/?fields=ratings{review_text,reviewer}* we receive the below message:

**(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.**

From the above blurb regarding Page Public Content Access, it sounds like we should be able to access "reviews", not just the overall review score. Are we doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of the permissions we have been granted?

We would like to avoid requiring users to 'login via facebook' and approve access, just to be able to read review data. We hoped that the Page Public Content Access permission would allow us to read all review data.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/managing#reviews both say that you need a page access token.

Comment: Thanks for your input @04FS - from what I've read, page access tokens expire every 60 days (where you are not the admin). Does this mean the only way to get the review data from our users pages, is to get approval from each individual user by having them authenticate via facebook and provide their consent every 60 days? We only want read access, not full manage_page access - but the 60 day limitation is the bigger issue for us. Is there any way around this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension: _“However, if you use a Page administrator token and your app has business permissions, the returned Page access token does not expire.”_

Comment: Thanks @04FS. I'm struggling to find much information on "Page Administrator" tokens. Will I be able to retrieve page administrator tokens (after prompting for their permission) for my customers facebook pages, to read their review data? Or is it only possible for the page 'owner' to retrieve a page administrator token?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens